# quicksort orderby id asc

Tags: haskell

How can I use quicksort to orderby ID ascending on the list and then show elements ? I have error: No instance for (Ord FigureType). My code is:

```
showRectangles [] = "No rectangles"
showRectangles x = concat (map showRectangle (qsort x))

showRectangle :: FigureType -> String
showRectangle (Figure id width height) = "id: " ++ show id ++ " width: " ++ show width ++ " height: " ++ show height ++ "\n";

data FigureType = Figure Int Int Int deriving(Show, Read)

qsort [] = []
qsort (x:xs) = qsort (filter (< x) xs) ++ [x] ++ qsort (filter (>= x) xs)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make `FigureType` comparable. The simplest thing to do is to make it derive [`Eq`](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#t%3aEq) and [`Ord`](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#t%3aOrd).

```
data FigureType = Figure Int Int Int deriving(Show, Read, Ord, Eq)
```

---

BTW, there is already a [`sort` function](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-List.html#v%3asort) in Data.List.

Comment: I haven't known about function sort() - could You tell me how can I use it to sort list by ID (first argument Figure) ?

Comment: @mrq: `sort x`. (If you derive from `Ord` it will order by width and height also, besides id.)

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that it don't know what `<` and `>=` means. You haven't told haskell that in that program.

To solve this, you must make an `instance Ord FigureTye`. I assume you've seen the syntax before. If not, you can look for *haskell type classes*. Since `Ord` is a subclass of `Eq`, you must also create the instance `Eq` for `FigureType`, however, this can just be derived by using `deriving(Show, Read, Eq)`. You could also write `deriving(Show, Read, Eq, Ord)`. But the auto-generated instance for `Ord` is probably not the implementation you have in mind.

---

Here is a link with the `Ord` typeclass, it says what minimal amount of functions you have to implement. http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#t:Ord

Here is Real world haskells chapter on type-classes. It doesn't cover any instance of `Ord` however. http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/using-typeclasses.html